# Can someone explain in detail how the clear works in this code?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS.  I have a Top, Right, and Content div.  I want it to look like this:

```
Top     Right

Content
```

However, it is showing up like this:

```
Top Content Right
```

I know I need a clear somewhere, but I am not sure where because I am unclear on how clears actually work, so can someone please explain the html code below on where I would apply the clear and what type of clear I would choose (left, right, or both).  Here is the stripped down html code:

```
<div style="float:left; width:600px; height:100px; 
            border:1px solid black;">Top</div>
<div style="float:right; width:200px; height:800px; 
            border:1px solid red;">Right</div>
<div style="width:500px; height:600px; 
            border:1px solid blue;">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `clear` on the Content `<div>`:

```
<div style="float:left; width:600px; height:100px; 
            border:1px solid black;">Top</div>
<div style="float:right; width:200px; height:800px; 
            border:1px solid red;">Right</div>
<div style="width:500px; height:600px; clear: both;
            border:1px solid blue;">Content</div>
```

This pushes the Content `<div>` so that it is below any floating elements (from the left *or* the right).

A side note: you probably should use CSS classes or the `id` attribute for convenience instead of inlining using `style`.

Comment: Do I have to use both in this case?

Comment: No, you can use either an ID or a class to accomplish the clearing. Depends on what other rules you have applied to the div and whether or not higher specificity is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Although it doesn't work in all cases the [WebToolkit's clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) technique helps alleviate most of these concerns.

### Usage

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div style="float:left;">left</div>
  <div style="float:right;">right</div>
</div>
<div>
  Some block content that doesn't overlap the floats
</div>
```

Also see the [demo](http://www.webtoolkit.info/demo/css/clearfix/demo.html)

### Code

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Whew, my brain is melting after looking at this.  Thanks though.

Comment: Thats the beauty of using this, you don't have to think about it just  wrap your content in a clearfix tag and done.

Answer (score 1):

Put a DIV that clears right after the Right div:

```
<div style="float:left; width:600px; height:100px; 
            border:1px solid black;">Top</div>
<div style="float:right; width:200px; height:800px; 
            border:1px solid red;">Right</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div style="width:500px; height:600px; 
            border:1px solid blue;">Content</div>
```

Comment: Why does this work? and can't I put the clear in one of the existing Divs without creating another one.